# wp_enqueue_scripts not working in custom theme

Tags: plugins, theme-development

This one may have been answered before but I could not find it anywhere.

I have created a custom theme and a plugin for my site. My theme's `functions.php` file only contain a `wp_nav_menu()` function for generating a menu.

Now in my plugin when I try to connect my CSS and JS with

```
function my_css_js() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'css_style', theme_URL . 'css/style.css' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'my-jquery_file', theme_URL . 'js/jquery.uploadfile.min.js', array(), null );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_css_js');
```

This does not load any CSS or JS in on my site.

As you can see I have used `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script`.

This is not loading the CSS and JS I need.

Is there anything I missed? When I use this same plugin with the same hook in ready made theme this works like charm.

I appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: Does your theme have [`wp_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) and [`wp_footer`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) in the templates?

Comment: You can try this `<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>`. It worked for me.

Comment: @Milo Thank you for your suggestion, and that was really right and i was missing wp_head in my theme section.

Comment: After I added <?php wp_footer(); ?> to the footer page and <?php wp_head(); ?> to the header page, it worked.

Comment: @Milo thanks!! such a stupid mistake I couldn't catch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found this small error in my code which stops `wp_enqueue_scripts()` to work in my theme was I forget to put `wp_head` in my head section.

For another person who may make same mistake are advised to check that they have include `wp_head` in head part and `wp_foot` at end of your theme.